# Hailstone Sequence C++ Recursion

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I'm having a bit of trouble converting the following code from using loops to using only recursion.

```
//longestHailstoneStartValue also cycles through each of the sequences from 1 
//to 'n' and after it is determined what the largest length is, it finds which 
//number corresponds with the longest length function.
//
//Sample input: '8'
//Sample output: '7'
//'7' is from the sequence starting with 7.

int longestHailstoneStartValue(int n)
{
    int u=1, w=0, z=0;

while(n>=u)
{
    if(w<lengthHailstone(u))
    {
        w=lengthHailstone(u);
        z=u;
    }

    u++;
}

return z;
}
```

I have to convert this to recursion and take anyway any extra variables that are not used/that have new values stored in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take out the variable `z` as it is practically useless and does nothing more than storing the value of `u`, this can increase memory for copying the value of `u` to `z`...

Also, read about [recursion to know more about what it *actually* is](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-recursion/)... It is simply calling the same method again and again from its own definition...

```
int longestHailstoneStartValue(int n)
{
    int u = 1, w = 0;
    if(w < lengthHailstone(u))
        w = lengthHailstone(u); // Removed 'z'...
    u++;
    /* '?' is the ternary operator... If n is greater or equal to u then print the
       original value of u (Note the 'u++') or else recursively call the function till
       the condition 'n >= u' is satisfied... */
    return n >= u ? u - 1 : longestHailstoneStartValue(n); /* 'u - 1' since 'u' will
                                                               increment by 1 even when
                                                               the given condition is
                                                               true... */
}
```

Comment: Btw, you probably want to store `lengthHailstone(u)` in variable to avoid to recompute the value.

Comment: That's equivalent to `int longestHailstoneStartValue(int n) { return n >= 2 ? 1 : longestHailstoneStartValue(n); }`, which will not work that well.